# EF 4 - Execution Error on Materialized Views

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, execution-time, materialized-views

I'm having an execution error on EF (EF 4, Database First) that appears in several windows services after they were in execution for a long time.

Here some details on the issue

1. This is not a compilation error, since system is compiling without
   problems
2. This is not a code error, since that code is executed
   without problems multiple times The error is happening in all
   environments we have.
3. Always happens in same place (and we have seen
   this error only in 'ContractDataEntities' edmx file, however, I have
   recreated this mapping several times, without any luck)
4. Is not a data error, because after restart the service, same records that
   used to fail are now processed without any kind of problems.
5. As an attempt to solve this, and based on the error message we got (The
   mapping and metadata information for EntityContainer
   'ContractDataEntities' no longer matches the information used to
   create the pre-generated views.) we have implemented a build
   generation that is activated on each build, so we know for sure that pre-generated views are always up to date

Regards.

---

Error Stack Trace.

***: ***  ---> System.Data.EntityCommandCompilationException: An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.MappingException: The mapping and metadata information for EntityContainer 'ContractDataEntities' no longer matches the information used to create the pre-generated views.
   at System.Data.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.SerializedAddGeneratedViewsInEntityViewContainer(MetadataWorkspace workspace, EntityViewContainer entityViewContainer, Dictionary`2 extentMappingViews)
   at System.Data.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.SerializedCollectViewsFromObjectCollection(MetadataWorkspace workspace, Dictionary`2 extentMappingViews)
   at System.Data.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.SerializedGetGeneratedViews(EntityContainer container)
   at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Evaluate>b__0()
   at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Result.GetValue()
   at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg)
   at System.Data.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.GetGeneratedView(EntitySetBase extent, MetadataWorkspace workspace, StorageMappingItemCollection storageMappingItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetGeneratedView(EntitySetBase extent)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ExpandView(Node node, ScanTableOp scanTableOp, IsOfOp& typeFilter)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ProcessScanTable(Node scanTableNode, ScanTableOp scanTableOp, IsOfOp& typeFilter)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(ScanTableOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ScanTableOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(ProjectOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ProjectOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(FilterOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.FilterOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(ProjectOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ProjectOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitSortOp(SortBaseOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.Visit(ConstrainedSortOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ConstrainedSortOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(ProjectOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ProjectOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitPhysicalOpDefault(PhysicalOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.Visit(PhysicalProjectOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.PhysicalProjectOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Process()
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Process(PlanCompiler planCompilerState, StructuredTypeInfo& typeInfo)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(List`1& providerCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount, Set`1& entitySets)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree)
   at System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Span span, ReadOnlyCollection`1 compiledQueryParameters)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.b__1[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)

Comment: Can you provide some code?  Can you tell anything about what circumstances the error happens in other than "the service has been in execution for a long time?"

Comment: The issue appears on several windows service that runs in background and periodically queries our DB and based on that results makes different actions (as part of those actions, new DB queries/updates are executed).

Comment: When the Windows Service is started, it runs without problems for certain time, but at some point it start to fail, with the error I have copied before. That particular portion of code was executed in the previous executions that didn't fail. Also the "db row" we are processing is not the problem, because if we just restart the windows service, the same row that used to be failing is now processed normally.

Comment: The error message we have is always the same, it happends any of the multiple queries we have. The only point in common between all the places where this is failing is the edmx file.
I have recreated it, re-generated the underlying cs code, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: one of the query that fails (it runs fine for some time, until it starts to fail) 
contractData.Lookup.MergeOption=MergeOption.NoTracking;
contractData.Lookup_Type.MergeOption=MergeOption.NoTracking;

var result = (from lookup in contractData.Lookup
              join lookupType in contractData.Lookup_Type on lookup.Lookup_Type_Id equals lookupType.Lookup_Type_Id
              where lookupType.Type == name
              select lookup.Description).ToList();
return result;